# auth_mellon httpd mod return Lasso error: [-205] Parsed XML is invalid

Tags: apache, azure-active-directory, centos7, saml, mellon

I'm trying to use auth_mellon mod to add SAML authentication to a website.
Followed the tutorial here : https://jdennis.fedorapeople.org/doc/mellon-install/mellon-install-guide.html
I'm not the one who generated the XML file on the IDP side (business with multiple services and another branch is administrating the Microsoft AD) but I get an error with the file :

`[Tue Jan 31 15:17:58.713662 2023] [auth_mellon:error] [pid 9005] [client 192.168.1.34:45544] Error adding metadata "/etc/httpd/saml2/idp_metadata.xml" to lasso server objects. Lasso error: [-205] Parsed XML is invalid.`

I don't find this error in the official lasso documentation, and even when I try switching to other random XML files for mellon I find online, it gives me the same error.
I'm unable to even access the URL fqdn.com/mellon/metadata as it tries to load the file and fails.

If someone has any hint ?
Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, in my case it was just some rights problem. Apache could not read the file referenced by MellonIdPMetadataFile (/etc/httpd/saml2/idp_metadata.xml in your case)
Giving correct permission to folder and file for apache user solved my issue.